# rs.getInt(1) not working properly

Tags: java, sql

I have the following syntax in SQL.

```
select Count(*) from queue_in_progress where CATEGORY_PK = 100001 AND SERVICE_STATUS = 0  AND SERVICE_CENTER_PK = 100001 AND SERVICE_COUNTER = 100001 ;
```

After this I got the following scenario .

[image]

But in my Java file I have the following code.

```
String sql="select Count(*)  from queue_in_progress where CATEGORY_PK = "+ ctgry_pk  
                        + "AND SERVICE_STATUS = 0  AND SERVICE_CENTER_PK = "+service_center+
                        " AND SERVICE_COUNTER = "+service_counter+" ;";

                rs =  getSeletRS(sql);
                int  count = rs.getInt(1);
```

Here I have got the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dbquery.SQLQuery.get_TOKEN_Pk(SQLQuery.java:160)
    at dbquery.SQLQuery.clickNextButton(SQLQuery.java:131)
    at dbquery.SQLQuery.main(SQLQuery.java:388)
```

I cannot understand why I got this error.

Comment: I guess the method `getSeletRS(String)` which you didn't show us returns `null`

Comment: I realize that `ctgry_pk`, `service_center`, and `service_counter` are *probably* numbers, and probably generated within your code rather than being user input. But still, if you're in the habit of creating SQL statements via string concatenation, you **will** be visited by [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) at some point.

Comment: Why int  cunt = rs.getInt(1); and no int  cunt = rs.getInt(0);??

Comment: Best variable name ever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that your `ResultSet` is not null.

```
rs =  getSeletRS(sql);
if(rs  != null){
   int  count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```